# Can someone explain how the limit of $ {(x-2)(n+1)\over 7(n+2)}$ as ${n \to \infty}$ is $x-2 \over 7$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Do the $n+1$ and $ n+2$ just cancel? I know they both go to infinity so wouldn't the whole problem just be infinity?

Comment: Simplify the entire fraction by *n*

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since $n+1 \sim n+2$ as $n\to \infty$, the limit is $\frac{x-2}{7}$

Answer (score 1):

More precisely,
since
$\frac{n+1}{n+2}
=1-\frac1{n+2}
$,
$\frac{(x-2)(n+1)}{7(n+2)}
=\frac{x-2}{7}(1-\frac1{n+2})
=\frac{x-2}{7}-\frac{x-2}{7(n+2)}
$
and the second term
goes to zero.